# Enabling Helvetica-Neue-Light in Bootstrap Navbar in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I have the following code:

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
      font-family: "HelveticaNeueLight", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light";
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #fff;
      margin-bottom:0px !important;
  }


.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
      font-family: "HelveticaNeueLight", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light";
      color: #fff;
      margin-bottom:0px !important;
      background: #222222;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Help</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact/a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Right Aligned Navbar</h3>
    <p>some text.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

In Firefox it's rendered wrongly like this:

[image]

But in other browsers (Chrome, Safari) it's displayed correctly:

[image]

How can enable `Helvetica Neue Light` correctly in firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it seems to be working to me.

```css
a {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Helvetica Neue (Light)</a>
```

I assumed that the font is only available by default on OS X, iOS. You might need use TypeKit or so to get a proper web font kit to work for all.

Comment: I also added Helvetica and sans-serif as fallbacks, obviously you'll need to apply those styles into your real class or id selectors. I use the `a` tag just as an example. Well, you have such high reps so I didn't bother to add more details, the question is really for how to use the font, not about Bootstrap or navbar etc. but feel free to comment for any further questions.

Answer (score 2):

In `style.css` of your theme there are multiple instance of: font-family: helveticaneue; As Helvetica Neue is not a standard web-safe font and since it's nomenclature can vary from system to system you may want to use something more like: font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "HelveticaNeue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; When using a non web-safe fonts it is always good to provide suitable alternatives if the font is not available.

Another alternative is to use a webfont `@font-face` to serve up the font.

Hope that helps!